# Change keystore of production app without pain? (trade app)

Tags: android, keystore, sign

My company want to buy an App from a developer(, say John), which is already on the Google Play.

John would like to sell the App to us, but he refuse to hand in the keystore(which is used to sign the App). The reason is that John signs other Apps with the same keystore.

According to my survey, an App CAN be transfered from one Google Play developer account to another, but due to different sign(by different keystore), the original users which already have downloaded the App will NO LONGER receive the update.

John will cooperate except handing in the keystore.

Is it possible that we can buy the App without getting the keystore, and the original user can continually receive the update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> John would like to sell the App to us, but he refuse to hand in the
>   keystore(which is used to sign the App). The reason is that John signs
>   other Apps with the same keystore.

This shows why each app should be signed with dedicated key

> Is it possible that we can buy the App without getting the keystore, and the original user can continually receive the update?

No, it is not possible. You will not be able to release any update to existing app if it is signed with different key.